# bash: retrieving number after a given string

Tags: bash

I have a file with the following:

```
  blabla sometinh#LULWUT-12342"asa
  haha"LULWUT-9635bgh
  haha'LULWUT-3679//stuff
```

The pattern LULWUT- always precedes a four of five number sequence. How can I retrive the number pattern?

For the example abode it would be

```
blabla sometinh#LULWUT-12342"asa > LULWUT-12342
haha"LULWUT-9635bgh              > LULWUT-9635
haha'LULWUT-3679//stuff          > LULWUT-3679
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To only match LULWUT- followed by a four or file digit pattern, you can  use this:

```
grep -o 'LULWUT-[0-9]\{4\}[0-9]\?' file
```

Comment: The grep -o is exactly what I was looking for ~ Thanks for the 4 or 5 numbers pattern too ~

Answer (score 7):

```
grep -o 'LULWUT-[0-9][0-9]*' file
```

which uses the nonstandard -o extension to grep (but that is nonetheless available on Mac OS, GNU and BSD systems).

Answer (score 2):

This is a bash-only solution.

```
shopt -s extglob # needed for the %%*() pattern below

while read line
do
    line_without_prefix="${line##*LULWUT}"    # remove longest prefix until LULWUT
    line_without_suffix="${line_without_prefix%%*([^0-9])}"   # remove longest non-digit suffix
    echo "LULWUT$line_without_suffix"
done

shopt -u extglob # undo, if extglob is not needed
```

Answer (score 1):

Your could try using the following command to replace (s ubstitute) text in the input file.

```
sed 's/.*LUL/LUL/' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

It will create a new file called newFile.txt

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -o 'LULWUT-[0-9]*' sample.txt
```

Comment: This would match LULWUTOMGBONKERSHALLOO0. I don't think that's what OP asked for.